# How to return a promise that's already 'thenned' in Javascript/ReactNative?

Tags: javascript, react-native, asynchronous

With this code below:

```
makeRequest = async (path, body) => {
    let client = await this.getClient()
    return this.client.post(path, body).then((response) => {
        console.log("Response on NetModule.makeRequest: ", response)
        if (!responseIsSuccess(response)) { toast("The response shows some errors.") }
        return response
    }).catch((error) => {
        toast("The request failed")
    })
}

login = async (username, password) => {
    let body = { username: username, password: password)
    return this.makeRequest('/login', body).then((response) => {
        console.log("Response on NetModule.login: ", response)
        if (responseIsSuccess(response)) { saveResponseToDisk(response); }
        return response
    })
}

btnLoginClick = async () => {
    const { username, password } = this.state
    NetModule.login(username, password).then((response) => {
        console.log("Response on LoginScreen.btnLoginClick: ", response)
        if (responseIsSuccess(response)) { this.props.navigation.navigate(home) }
        return response
    })
}
```

The response is:

```
Response on NetModule.login: undefined
Response on LoginScreen.btnLoginClick: undefined
Response on NetModule.makeRequest: <has response>
```

Why it's like this? How can I make that the response is like this (and in this order):

```
Response on NetModule.makeRequest: <has response>
Response on NetModule.login: <has same response>
Response on LoginScreen.btnLoginClick: <has same response>
```

Comment: Then also returns a promise .

Comment: @SijuSamson what do you mean? Like `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(response))` ?

Comment: @ChenLiYong You need to `return await` in `login` and `makeRequest`.

Comment: @MuhammadTalhaAkbar you can return a Promise from an async function.  await isn't necessary.  It is however a sign that he's unnecessarily wrapping Promises and making things more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mix and match `async/await` and `.then` if you don't have to. The current problem is that `btnLoginClick` doesn't "wait" for `NetModule.login` to finish. It returns immediately. `return NetModule.login` would solve that but we can do better:

```
makeRequest = async (path, body) => {
    let client = await this.getClient()
    try {
      let response = await client.post(path, body)
      console.log("Response on NetModule.makeRequest: ", response)
      if (!responseIsSuccess(response)) { toast("The response shows some errors.") }
      return response
    } catch (error) {
        toast("The request failed")
    }
}

login = async (username, password) => {
    let body = { username: username, password: password)
    let response = await this.makeRequest('/login', body)
    console.log("Response on NetModule.login: ", response)
    if (responseIsSuccess(response)) { saveResponseToDisk(response); }
    return response
}

btnLoginClick = async () => {
    const { username, password } = this.state
    let response = await NetModule.login(username, password);
    console.log("Response on LoginScreen.btnLoginClick: ", response)
    if (responseIsSuccess(response)) { this.props.navigation.navigate(home) }
    return response
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I've tried to avoid `await` as much as possible because sometimes it can hogs thread flows, and also because of the `.catch` clause, but maybe I'll try to use the `try ... catch` method instead. Thanks.

Comment: The whole point of using an `async` function is to be able to use `await` in it. If you don't use `await` then you don't have to declare a function as `async`. It's more or less just syntactic sugar for `.then` anyways.